# <DIV> inside <FONT> and <SPAN> is not working in xmlWorker

Tags: java, html, itext, html-to-pdf, xmlworker

we are using iText XML Worker version 5 to generate PDF from HTML 
snippet but it seems like Text1 wrapping by DIV is not coming in PDF.
any idea why DIV tag is not working in above snippet?

I Have HTML Snippet code like below

```
<HTML>
     <BODY>
          <DIV> 
              <FONT>   
                  <SPAN>  
                    --- this text is missing in pdf
                    <DIV> Text1</DIV>           
                  </SPAN>
              </FONT>
         </DIV> 
     </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Maybe because the HTML Spec doesn't allow DIV inside of SPAN and the parser therefore ignores it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not common practice to place a DIV tag (which is a block element) inside a SPAN (which is a inline element), I get an output.

As far as I know the FONT tag is not supported in HTML5. So maybe removing the FONT tag will do it?

Comment: But these these Tags are generated by HTML Editor in Sencha where we dont have control to force HTML Spec standards

Comment: Feed your HTML through a HTML sanitizer before you feed it to XMLWorker. JSoup is a pupular library. iText 7 uses it in pdfHTML. On that note: please try to convert this HTML snippet using iText 7, because iText 5 is End Of Life.